# What is the probability of at least an elderly person in my neighborhood dying in the next 1 year?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, conditional-probability

This is a random question that came to my mind when I went for a long run this morning. I tried to solve in it my mind and then on paper, but the number I come up with doesn't feel good intuitively.

First let me formulate the question and then explain my approach,

"What is the probability of at least an elderly person in my neighborhood dying in the next 1 year?"

I assumed,

1. let "Elderly person" be anyone with $age \geq 70$.
2. let Neighborhood mean that there are $50$ houses near my house.
3. there can be only a single elderly person residing in a house and there is 25% chance of  an elderly person residing in a house(let it be called $E$ where $P(E)$=.25).
4. let X be a r.v. defining the current age of an elderly person, which is $unif(70, 100)$.
5. let Y be a r.v. defining the age at which an elderly person dies, which is $unif(70,100)$.

My solution,
Let,
$A$ be an event that an elderly person dies(anywhere) in the next 1 year,
$B$ be an event that an elderly person resides in a house and dies in the next 1 year,

$$P(A) = P(X+1>Y|X<Y) = \frac{30^2 - 29^2}{30^2} = 0.065$$
$$P(A^c) = 1-0.065 = 0.9345$$

$$P(B) = P(A| E)P(E) + P(A| E^C)P(E^C) = P(A|E)P(E) =  0.065*.25 = 0.01625 $$

$\textbf{Note}$: The idea is if there are 50 houses in the neighborhood, not all houses have an elderly person residing there. P(A) is in "general" probability of any elderly person dying in next 1 year. P(B) is supposed to mean if an elderly person resides in a house "and" he will die in next year.

$P($at least an elderly person dies in my neighborhood) = $1 - P($none of the elderly person dies in my neighborhood).

$P($none of the elderly person dies in my neighborhood) = $(1-P(B))^{50} = (1-0.01625)^{50} = 0.4408$

Therefore, I concluded that
$P($ at least an elderly person dies in my neighborhood) = $1-0.4407 = 0.5593$,

Does the solution seem fine? Am I incorrect in my assumptions or solution? Please help.

Comment: It seems to me that the way you calculate P(B) is incorrect

Comment: @blue Thanks for commenting, What do you think would be a better approach for P(B)? and also What are your thoughts on P(A)?

Comment: Well honestly, as I was reading your question, I was struggling a bit to understand what are all the things you are taking as relevant here. I think the way you wanted to use X and Y is smart, but I don't really see where you're headed with A and B. You differentiate between person dying and person dying IN THE HOUSE but, from the way you defined the problem, it seems that the only possible "ambient" is the house. The expression you've used to calculate P(B) is literally equal to P(A) and you've somehow managed to get a number that's not P(A)...I don't know.

Comment: Ok I see. The idea is if there are 50 houses in the neighborhood, not all houses have an elderly person residing there. P(A) is in "general"  probability of any elderly person dying in next 1 year. P(B) is supposed to mean if an elderly person resides in a house "and" he will die in next year.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think P(A) is also incorrect, I think it's supposed to be $\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{29^2}{30^2})$. But I still think the way you've set up your problem isn't really good and here's why: first of all, I think using expression "in the house" is a bit misleading. It looks like you're differentiating between a person from your neighbourhood dying in the hospital vs in the house, when actually you use to state that the person who died was from your neighbourhood. Secondly, A is the event of an elderly person dying...anywhere?

Comment: So, when establishing the connection between A and B, it seems your "universe" should be the elderly and you should have the probability of an elderly being in your neighbourhood (as opposed to an elderly being outside of your neighbourhood). Instead, your universe in the beginning are people from your neighbourhood and then your assumption is the probability of a person being an elderly if it's in your neighbourhood (P(E)), if I understand correctly?

Comment: You don't have to limit your universe to the elderly, you can observe literally all the people in the world, but then you'd need the probability of a person being in your neighbourhood.

Comment: Actually, I think I've made a mistake. Your calculation for P(A) is correct. However, problems with the way this question is set up still remain.

Comment: @blue Sorry for the late reply. Yes, you understood correctly. I have reframed the explanation given your valuable insights.

And regarding P(A) calculation. Actually you are partially correct. I did a mistake. I calculated $P(A) = P(X+1<Y | X<Y)$  while I should calculate  $P(A) = P(X+1>Y | X<Y)$. Corrected that.

Comment: Now number actually looks more relatable. But still not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: Oh yeah right, that's why I thought P(A) is incorrect, but in the I've made a mistake too, I think it's ok now.

Comment: The thing is: P(B) is still suspicious, because $$P(A|E)P(E)+P(A|E^c)P(E^c)=P(AE)+P(AE^c)=P(A)$$ so, the way you've written it, you basically say that $P(B)=P(A)$. I think what you meant to do is: $P(B)=P(B|E)P(E)+P(B|E^c)P(E^c)$, but this seems pointless because what is $P(B|E^c)$? Probability that an elderly person dies if person isn't an elderly?

Comment: We go back to the way you've set up the problem. Your "unverse" in the beginning are people who are in your neighbourhood, so, in your calculations, you either have to pretend there are no people outside of your neighbourhood (which means you can't have an event such as A) or you have to have something like a probability that a person (not necessarily elderly) is in your neighbourhood. Try thinking about this: what is $E^c$?

Comment: @blue " you have to have something like a probability that a person (not necessarily elderly) is in your neighbourhood". Understood your point completely. And I believe its about describing the sample population first then commenting on "elderly" subset. Something in this direction. Thanks alot for helping. I understood the inaccuracies in my line of thoughts.